better way of initializing python object method variables with object variable values if not passed in
I have many object methods where I can pass in values, but want to be able to default them to the object variable if not passed. Something like this example that I came up to illustrate what I want to do:
from datetime import datetime
class Appointment :
  def __init__(self, resource, startTime:datetime, endTime:datetime) :
    self.resource = resource
    self.startTime = startTime
    self.endTime = endTime
 
  def isValid(self, startTime:datetime=None, endTime:datetime=None) :
  # would be nice if I could:
  # def isValid(self, startTime:datetime=self.startTime, endTime:datetime=self.endTime) :
    # first way of initializing
    if not startTime :
      startTime = self.startTime

    # second way of initializing
    endTime = endTime if endTime else self.endTime
    return self.resource.isAvailable(startTime, endTime)

Those are the two ways (three if you count the illegal syntax one) I can think of doing it. First has lots of nesting and more lines, second has redundant assignment, so I dislike both. Is there a better way? Is there a way to make the illegal syntax one work?

I'd just go with the first personally. Although it kinda sounds like isValid might work better as a static method than an object one?

Function default arguments are evaluated at the time the function was defined.  A default like self.startTime is utterly impossible, as no such thing as self exists at that point in time.  (Which self would it be, anyway?  Presumably you're creating more than one of these objects over the lifetime of your program.)  Personally, I would use startTime or self.startTime in the function, assuming that no actual value for the parameter is falsy.

I think the reason this feels awkward is because what you're trying to do is not really idiomatic. In my eyes, the isValid method should not take any parameters (other than self), and should only tell you if the instance itself which you've initialized is valid. The fact that you want to be able to pass in parameters only sometimes suggests that you're trying to get this instance method to behave like an instance method sometimes, and other times like a static method of the class.

@PaulM. agreed, but this example is contrived code to illustrate the scenario. My thinking was that this contrived script has a reschedule method that checks if new schedule isValid before (I didn't want to use that as example as there are better ways of doing rescheduling as well! lol). My work code is entirely different domain. This was the simplest code I could come up with to be as clear of the scenario and the solutions I thought of.

@jasonharper if the defaults are evaluated at runtime instead of compile time, it would be clear. It would be the self that was in the first param. There should be no other "self" in context; otherwise, what self would self be referring to in the first param?

I believe the best approach would be the following:
from datetime import datetime


class Appointment:
    def __init__(self, resource, start_time: datetime, end_time: datetime):
        self.resource = resource
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time

    def is_valid(self, start_time: datetime = None, end_time: datetime = None):
        return self.resource.is_available(
            start_time=start_time or self.start_time, 
            end_time=end_time or self.end_time
        )


Yes, but it's still redundant assignment, as I still need a variable. This example, as stated, is just an example. my real code has multiple uses for the value. So I would have to initialize the var or use the or syntax throughout. Initializing the var would be redundant assignment. Using the or syntax throughout is more vulnerable to bugs. If I forgot it in one case, future maintainer would be confused if that was intentional or not. Your solution would be valid if my example was my actual code. thanks
